# A question about visualizing "Lucas-Kanade(optical flow)" algorithm formula

Tags: derivatives, algorithms, graphing-functions

I am reading O'Reilly's OpenCV 3 book. In keypoints section(for tracking objects), there is an algorithm named "Lucas-Kanade". in the below image it tries to give a visualization of it but I can not understand the derivitive of time `I(t)` in this image, also what is the vertical-axis in this pic?

[image]

> Figure 16-5, which shows an “edge”—consisting of a high value on the
>   left and a low value on the right—that is moving to the right along
>   the x-axis. Our goal is to identify the velocity v at which the edge
>   is moving, as plotted in the upper part of Figure 16-5. In the lower
>   part of the figure, we can see that our measurement of this velocity
>   is just “rise over run,” where the rise is over time and the run is
>   the slope (spatial derivative). The negative sign corrects for the
>   slope of x.

Comment: The vertical axis is $I(x,t)$. The algorithm used here is essentially relying on differentiation with respect to a parameter. If you look at units only, then $(\partial I/\partial t)/(\partial I/\partial x)$ has units of velocity.

Comment: @AdrianKeister: I am looking to know why the I(t) is vertical line in the below plot? How is it calculated?